# pandas: exclude zeros when aggregating

Tags: python, pandas

Consider some sample pandas dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9],
                   [0, 0, 0]],
                   columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Now, I want to aggregate each column (say calculating the mean) where I want to exclude the zeros. I can see there is `agg` function that can be called but I could not figure out how to exclude the zeros when calculating the mean.

I know when mapping the columns, I need to somehow filter out the zeros but I cannot figure out how to include that in the call to the `df.agg()` function.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the 0 with `np.nan` so you can call your agg function

`df.replace(0,np.nan).agg(np.mean)`

Comment: `np.mean` or `'mean'`, not `'np.mean'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use methods `where` and `mask` to replace zeros with `NaN`:

```
df.where(df!=0).agg('mean')
```

or

```
df.mask(df==0).agg('mean')
```

Output:

```
A    4.0
B    5.0
C    6.0
```